# Merging two YouTube API scripts

Tags: python, api, youtube

EDIT: I installed flags to run the second script, but no luck for YouTube users partnered with third party MCNs, monetization cannot be enabled using API for them.

I found this, older version of a YouTube upload script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Copyright (C) 2013 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""Simple command-line sample for Youtube Partner API.

Command-line application that creates an asset, uploads and claims a video for that asset.

Usage:
  $ python upload_monetize_video_example.py --file=VIDEO_FILE --channelID=CHANNEL_ID \
      [--title=VIDEO_TITLE] [--description=VIDEO_DESCRIPTION] [--category=CATEGORY_ID] \
      [--keywords=KEYWORDS] [--privacyStatus=PRIVACY_STATUS] [--policyId=POLICY_ID] 

You can also get help on all the command-line flags the program understands
by running:

  $ python upload_monetize_video_example.py --help
"""

__author__ = 'jeffy+pub@google.com (Jeffrey Posnick)'

import httplib
import httplib2
import logging
import os
import random
import sys
import time

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run
from optparse import OptionParser


# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, httplib.NotConnected,
  httplib.IncompleteRead, httplib.ImproperConnectionState,
  httplib.CannotSendRequest, httplib.CannotSendHeader,
  httplib.ResponseNotReady, httplib.BadStatusLine,)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = (500, 502, 503, 504,)

# The message associated with the HTTP 401 error that's returned when a request
# is authorized by a user whose account is not associated with a YouTube
# content owner.
INVALID_CREDENTIALS = "Invalid Credentials"

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# See the "Registering your application" instructions for an explanation
# of how to find these values:
# https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/guides/registering_an_application
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access Google APIs, please visit:
#   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# The local file used to store the cached OAuth 2 credentials after going
# through a one-time browser-based login.
CACHED_CREDENTIALS_FILE = "%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0]

YOUTUBE_SCOPES = (
  # An OAuth 2 access scope that allows for full read/write access.
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
  # A scope that grants access to YouTube Partner API functionality.
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner",)
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
YOUTUBE_CONTENT_ID_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtubePartner"
YOUTUBE_CONTENT_ID_API_VERSION = "v1"

# Helpful message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you need to populate the client_secrets.json file at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

def parse_options():
  parser = OptionParser()
  parser.add_option("--file", dest="file", help="Video file to upload")
  parser.add_option("--title", dest="title", help="Video title",
    default="Test Title")
  parser.add_option("--description", dest="description",
    help="Video description",
    default="Test Description")
  parser.add_option("--category", dest="category",
    help="Numeric video category. " +
      "See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list",
    default="22")
  parser.add_option("--keywords", dest="keywords",
    help="Video keywords, comma separated", default="")
  parser.add_option("--privacyStatus", dest="privacyStatus",
    help="Video privacy status: public, private or unlisted",
    default="public")
  parser.add_option("--policyId", dest="policyId",
    help="Optional id of a saved claim policy")
  parser.add_option("--channelId", dest="channelId",
    help="Id of the channel to upload to. Must be managed by your CMS account")
  (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

  return options

def get_authenticated_services():
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(
    CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=" ".join(YOUTUBE_SCOPES),
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE
  )

  storage = Storage(CACHED_CREDENTIALS_FILE)
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(flow, storage)

  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

  youtube_partner = build(YOUTUBE_CONTENT_ID_API_SERVICE_NAME,
    YOUTUBE_CONTENT_ID_API_VERSION, http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

  return (youtube, youtube_partner)

def get_content_owner_id(youtube_partner):
  try:
    content_owners_list_response = youtube_partner.contentOwners().list(
      fetchMine=True
    ).execute()
  except HttpError, e:
    if INVALID_CREDENTIALS in e.content:
      logging.error("Your request is not authorized by a Google Account that "
        "is associated with a YouTube content owner. Please delete '%s' and "
        "re-authenticate with an account that is associated "
        "with a content owner." % CACHED_CREDENTIALS_FILE)
      exit(1)
    else:
      raise

  # This returns the CMS user id of the first entry returned
  # by youtubePartner.contentOwners.list()
  # See https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/contentOwners/list
  # Normally this is what you want, but if you authorize with a Google Account
  # that has access to multiple YouTube content owner accounts, you need to
  # iterate through the results.
  return content_owners_list_response["items"][0]["id"]

def upload(youtube, content_owner_id, options):
  if options.keywords:
    tags = options.keywords.split(",")
  else:
    tags = None

  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    onBehalfOfContentOwner=content_owner_id,
    onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel=options.channelId,
    part="snippet,status",
    body=dict(
      snippet=dict(
        title=options.title,
        description=options.description,
        tags=tags,
        categoryId=options.category
      ),
      status=dict(
        privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
      )
    ),
    # chunksize=-1 means that the entire file will be uploaded in a single
    # HTTP request. (If the upload fails, it will still be retried where it
    # left off.) This is usually a best practice, but if you're using Python
    # older than 2.6 or if you're running on App Engine, you should set the
    # chunksize to something like 1024 * 1024 (1 megabyte).
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )

  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  duration_seconds=0
  while response is None:
    try:
      logging.debug("Uploading file...")

      start_seconds = time.time()
      status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
      delta_seconds = time.time() - start_seconds
      duration_seconds += delta_seconds

      if "id" in response:
        return (response["id"], duration_seconds)
      else:
        logging.error("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" %
          response)
        exit(1)
    except HttpError, e:
      if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
        error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,
                                                             e.content)
      else:
        raise
    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS, e:
      error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

    if error is not None:
      logging.error(error)
      retry += 1
      if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
        logging.error("No longer attempting to retry.")
        exit(1)

      max_sleep = 2 ** retry
      sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
      logging.debug("Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds)
      time.sleep(sleep_seconds)

def create_asset(youtube_partner, content_owner_id, title, description):
  # This creates a new asset corresponding to a video on the web.
  # The asset is linked to the corresponding YouTube video via a
  # claim that will be created later.
  body = dict(
    type="web",
    metadata=dict(
      title=title,
      description=description
    )
  )

  assets_insert_response = youtube_partner.assets().insert(
    onBehalfOfContentOwner=content_owner_id,
    body=body
  ).execute()

  return assets_insert_response["id"]

def set_asset_ownership(youtube_partner, content_owner_id, asset_id):
  # This specifies that content_owner_id owns 100% of the asset worldwide.
  # Adjust as needed.
  body = dict(
    general=[dict(
      owner=content_owner_id,
      ratio=100,
      type="exclude",
      territories=[]
    )]
  )

  youtube_partner.ownership().update(
    onBehalfOfContentOwner=content_owner_id,
    assetId=asset_id,
    body=body
  ).execute()

def claim_video(youtube_partner, content_owner_id, asset_id, video_id,
  policy_id):
  # policy_id can be set to the id of an existing policy, which can be obtained
  # via youtubePartner.policies.list()
  # See https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/policies/list
  # If you later update that existing policy, the claim will also be updated.
  if policy_id:
    policy = dict(
      id=policy_id
    )
  # If policy_id is not provided, a new inline policy is created.
  else:
    policy = dict(
      rules=[dict(
        action="monetize"
      )]
    )

  body = dict(
    assetId=asset_id,
    videoId=video_id,
    policy=policy,
    contentType="audiovisual"
  )

  claims_insert_response = youtube_partner.claims().insert(
    onBehalfOfContentOwner=content_owner_id,
    body=body
  ).execute()

  return claims_insert_response["id"]

def set_advertising_options(youtube_partner, content_owner_id, video_id):
  # This enables the true view ad format for the given video.
  # Adjust as needed.
  body = dict(
    adFormats=["trueview_instream"]
  )

  youtube_partner.videoAdvertisingOptions().update(
    videoId=video_id,
    onBehalfOfContentOwner=content_owner_id,
    body=body
  ).execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  )

  options = parse_options()

  if options.file is None or not os.path.exists(options.file):
    logging.error("Please specify a valid file using the --file= parameter.")
    exit(1)

  # The channel ID looks something like "UC..." and needs to correspond to a
  # channel managed by the YouTube content owner authorizing the request.
  # youtube.channels.list(part="snippet", managedByMe=true,
  #                       onBehalfOfContentOwner=*CONTENT_OWNER_ID*)
  # can be used to retrieve a list of managed channels and their channel IDs.
  # See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
  if options.channelId is None:
    logging.error("Please specify a channel ID via the --channelId= parameter.")
    exit(1)

  (youtube, youtube_partner) = get_authenticated_services()

  content_owner_id = get_content_owner_id(youtube_partner)
  logging.info("Authorized by content owner ID '%s'." % content_owner_id)

  (video_id, duration_seconds) = upload(youtube, content_owner_id, options)
  logging.info("Successfully uploaded video ID '%s'." % video_id)

  file_size_bytes = os.path.getsize(options.file)
  logging.debug("Uploaded %d bytes in %0.2f seconds (%0.2f megabytes/second)." %
    (file_size_bytes, duration_seconds,
      (file_size_bytes / (1024 * 1024)) / duration_seconds))

  asset_id = create_asset(youtube_partner, content_owner_id,
    options.title, options.description)
  logging.info("Created new asset ID '%s'." % asset_id)

  set_asset_ownership(youtube_partner, content_owner_id, asset_id)
  logging.info("Successfully set asset ownership.")

  claim_id = claim_video(youtube_partner, content_owner_id, asset_id,
    video_id, options.policyId)
  logging.info("Successfully claimed video.")

  set_advertising_options(youtube_partner, content_owner_id, video_id)
  logging.info("Successfully set advertising options.")

  logging.info("All done!")
```

And also a newer script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib
import httplib2
import os
import random
import sys
import time

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, httplib.NotConnected,
  httplib.IncompleteRead, httplib.ImproperConnectionState,
  httplib.CannotSendRequest, httplib.CannotSendHeader,
  httplib.ResponseNotReady, httplib.BadStatusLine)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
# authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ("public", "private", "unlisted")


def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
  tags = None
  if options.keywords:
    tags = options.keywords.split(",")

  body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.title,
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
    )
  )

  # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=",".join(body.keys()),
    body=body,
    # The chunksize parameter specifies the size of each chunk of data, in
    # bytes, that will be uploaded at a time. Set a higher value for
    # reliable connections as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    # value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    #
    # Setting "chunksize" equal to -1 in the code below means that the entire
    # file will be uploaded in a single HTTP request. (If the upload fails,
    # it will still be retried where it left off.) This is usually a best
    # practice, but if you're using Python older than 2.6 or if you're
    # running on App Engine, you should set the chunksize to something like
    # 1024 * 1024 (1 megabyte).
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )

  resumable_upload(insert_request)

# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.
def resumable_upload(insert_request):
  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  while response is None:
    try:
      print "Uploading file..."
      status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
      if 'id' in response:
        print "Video id '%s' was successfully uploaded." % response['id']
      else:
        exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
    except HttpError, e:
      if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
        error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,
                                                             e.content)
      else:
        raise
    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS, e:
      error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

    if error is not None:
      print error
      retry += 1
      if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
        exit("No longer attempting to retry.")

      max_sleep = 2 ** retry
      sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
      print "Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds
      time.sleep(sleep_seconds)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  argparser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="Video file to upload")
  argparser.add_argument("--title", help="Video title", default="Test Title")
  argparser.add_argument("--description", help="Video description",
    default="Test Description")
  argparser.add_argument("--category", default="22",
    help="Numeric video category. " +
      "See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list")
  argparser.add_argument("--keywords", help="Video keywords, comma separated",
    default="")
  argparser.add_argument("--privacyStatus", choices=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES,
    default=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES[0], help="Video privacy status.")
  args = argparser.parse_args()

  if not os.path.exists(args.file):
    exit("Please specify a valid file using the --file= parameter.")

  youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
  try:
    initialize_upload(youtube, args)
  except HttpError, e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

I would like to convert the claiming and monetization features from the old script to the new one, but haven't figured out how to do that yet. I assume it would be a breeze for an expienced Python/Google API programmer. Can you help?

I tried some merging based on improting functions and rewriting flows, but that has not worked so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API monetization features cannot be used unless you are a direct YouTube partner, MCNs are unsupported.